# Pandas is turning some empty values to None

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a script that takes a DF from google sheet via the API, all is working fine but i need to replace all the empty cells in one column with -1 as a string, for that i´m using this code

```
data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(values_data)
data['Column_name'] = data['Column_name'].replace('', '-1')
```

That works in most of the cases, but in some cases pandas don´t replace the value and if i print the content of the cell it says is None, but in the g-sheet the cell is empty as the rest

Comment: Try `df = df.fillna(value=-1)` which introduced to do so!

Comment: df = df.fillna(value=-1) this works , Thanks